# Getting the width of Email Content using the Block SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, content, sdk

I have made a custom content block inside Content Builder using the Block SDK and I need to figure out the width of the space inside of the email (when editing) so I can set the width of the images created while using my custom block.

For example, if there is a 2 column layout in the email and each column is 300px, I need that data passed through so I can set image widths to 300px.

Here is the documentations: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk

I've tried `getData()` ect to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality does not exist and it would be tricky to build and use, as width of a block can change based on [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and the size of the client. Returning a width that is contextual and not guaranteed could lead to poor end user experience.

Based on your example, it seems you can achieve the same result using [relative styles](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dim_width_percent) (like a 100% width on your image) and it would be more robust.

Comment: That makes sense, and I agree with you on a high level. The problem is that images can't use relative styles in older outlook versions so I need a fallback at the very least with a hard-coded width. Do you know a way around this Outlook bug worth exploring?